# Can't Find SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 uninstall option

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Supposedly, the method to uninstall a service pack to SQL Server 2008 R2 (and other versions after a certain point) is through Control Panel > Programs and Features.

I think it's supposed to be listed as "Service Pack 2 for SQL Server 2008 R2" or something similar to that.

However, I can find no such option. I want to be able to roll back upon applying this update to production systems.

Comment: Will this works in your case ? http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1824/sql-server-2008-service-pack-1-sp1-uninstall/

Comment: Thanks! It wasn't quite the same since I'm not on XP/2003, but I had to click on "View Installed Updates" in Windows Server 2008 R2